# How do you use a LWRP with chef?

Tags: chef-infra, lwrp

I'm new to chef, and I'm trying to setup a wrapper cookbook to manage logstash. The [cookbook I am wrapping](https://github.com/lusis/chef-logstash) uses LWRP.

How do you manage a config file using a LWRP?

Here is the wrapper cookbook that I have so far

recipes/default.rb

```
include_recipe 'apt::default'
include_recipe 'java::default'
include_recipe 'logstash::server'
```

attributes/default.rb

```
default['logstash']['instance_default']['elasticsearch_cluster'] = 'example-elasticsearch'
default['logstash']['instance_default']['elasticsearch_ip'] = 'elasticsearch01.example.com'
default['logstash']['instance_default']['elasticsearch_port'] = '9200'
default['logstash']['instance_default']['elasticsearch_embedded'] = false
```

Berksfile

```
source "https://supermarket.chef.io"

metadata

cookbook 'logstash', git: 'https://github.com/lusis/chef-logstash.git'
```

According to the documentation, there is an example of using a LWRP in the [.kitchen.yml](https://github.com/lusis/chef-logstash/blob/master/.kitchen.yml), but I'm not sure how to use it.

Where do I put the LWRP definitions?
What does a LWRP look like inside a wrapper cookbook?

**Update**

Here is what I have tried:

In `recipe/default.rb` I've added the following

```
include_recipe 'apt::default'
include_recipe 'java::default'
include_recipe 'logstash::server'


logstash_config 'config/foobar_output_elasticsearch.conf.erb' do
  action [:create]
  notifies :restart, "logstash_service[#{name}]"
end
```

Then inside `templates/default/config/foobar_output_elasticsearch.conf.erb` I have the following

```
foobar
```

Yet when I run a kitchen converge, the file is not created

**Update2**

According to cheeseplus in the irc channel, you should be able to use a LWRP like so:

```
default['logstash']['instance_default']['config_templates_cookbook'] = 'config/foobar_output_elasticsearch.conf.erb'
```

https://github.com/lusis/chef-logstash/issues/367

Unfortunately it doesn't work.

**Update3**

I've also tried setting attributes in my default.rb like so:

```
default['logstash']['instance_default']['config_templates_cookbook'] = 'My-Wrapper-Cookobook'
default['logstash']['instance_default']['config_templates']['foobar'] = 'config/foobar_output_elasticsearch.conf.erb'
```

**Update4**

I've also tried setting the parameters in the resource directly with no luck.

```
logstash_config 'foobar' do
  templates_cookbook 'MY-Wrapper-Cookbook'
  templates 'config/foobar_output_elasticsearch.conf.erb'
  action [:create]
  notifies :restart, "logstash_service[#{name}]"
end
```

**Update5**

[Looking at this example](https://github.com/lusis/chef-logstash/issues/367), I've also tried the following syntax.

```
default['logstash']['instance_default']['config_templates'] = {
'input_redis' => 'config/input_redis.conf.erb',
'filter_syslog' => 'config/filter_syslog.conf.erb',
'output_elasticsearch' => 'config/output_elasticsearch.conf.erb',
'foobar' => 'config/foobar_output_elasticsearch.conf.erb'
}
```

Comment: I've also tried asking the author directly. https://github.com/lusis/chef-logstash/issues/398

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out, The syntax was correct and working, however the test kitchen file wasn't loading the correct cookbooks.

Here is the final working output

attributes/default.rb

```
default['logstash']['instance_default']['elasticsearch_cluster'] = 'foobar-elasticsearch'
default['logstash']['instance_default']['elasticsearch_ip'] = 'elasticsearch01.example.com'
default['logstash']['instance_default']['elasticsearch_port'] = '9200'
default['logstash']['instance_default']['elasticsearch_embedded'] = false

default['logstash']['instance_default']['config_templates_cookbook'] = 'foobar-Logstash-Indexer'

default['logstash']['instance_default']['config_templates']['foobar'] = 'config/foobar_output_elasticsearch.conf.erb'
```

recipes/default.rb

```
include_recipe 'apt'
include_recipe 'java'
include_recipe 'logstash::server'
```

.kitchen.yml

```
---
driver:
  name: vagrant
driver_config:
  require_chef_omnibus: true
  use_vagrant_berkshelf_plugin: true
  customize:
    memory: 512
    cpus: 1

provisioner:
  name: chef_solo

platforms:
  - name: ubuntu-12.04
  - name: centos-5.10
  - name: centos-6.5
  - name: centos-7.0
  - name: fedora-20
  - name: debian-7.6

suites:
  - name: server
    run_list:
      - recipe[apt::default]
      - recipe[java::default]
      # - recipe[logstash::server]
      - recipe[foobar-Logstash-Indexer::default]
```